# What is the usefulness of second order logic?

Tags: logic, soft-question

I understand that second order logic does not have a sound and complete proof system but I was wondering, how this lack of sound and complete proof system affects the usefulness of the SoL.

As far as I understand SoL is a very strong logic that allows us to pin down the structure of Natural numbers. However, not having a sound and complete proof system means that there will be statements in the language that cannot be proved  using finite steps via computers as opposed to FoL. **Is my understanding correct?**

My question is that how not being able to prove things using finite steps affect the usage of SoL? 
**Is it deemed useless because proofs cannot be checked by computers or is it still useful and popular among mathematicians?**

Comment: Second-order logic is not sound?

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean it is not sound? Do you mean it does not have a sound proof system? If yes the question is that what is the consequence of not being sound?

Comment: You were the one who said second-order logic wasn't sound. Generally, the statement is second order logic is not both consistent and complete. Consistency, as far as I understand, is different than soundness.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern abk said that "second-order logic does not have a sound and complete proof system," but that's different from second-order logic not being sound. The thing that's not sound is any purported complete proof system.

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Sorry didnot see the question mark. SoL doesnot have a [sound and complete proof system](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-sound-and-complete-proof-system). Yes soundness is different from consistency. I have not seen anywhere saying that SoL is not consistent. I guess consistency is to do with having a model or not and not to do with SoL or FoL.